# How can I create a unique list of data across multiple rows AND columns?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

Google Sheets has a `UNIQUE()` function which when given a column of values, will output a column of all unique values.

This works well for column-specific data, however, you have multiple columns and rows of data that needs to be summarized, this won't work.  This is because if you include a 2-dimensional range into `UNIQUE()` the end results are two dimensional, with only each column being summarized.

Is there a function or way to summarize all values across an entire 2-dimensional range?

**REASONING:**

I have a large list of businesses.  Each column is a type of business, and each row contains values of business names.  I need to create an end-list of all businesses that are provided throughout the entire source sheet.  I don't need unique values per column. I need unique values across the entire document.

Comment: you can stack columns in array

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
=UNIQUE({A:A;B:B;C:C})
```

[image: 1]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(QUERY(TO_TEXT({A:A;B:B;C:C}), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")))
```

[image: 3]

Answer (score 13):

```
=unique(flatten(A1:Z))
```

I think this will work and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, you may want to stack the columns vertically. You can do that by adding a semi-colon between them, like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(QUERY(TO_TEXT({C:C;D:D;E:E;F:F}), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")))
```