# Multiple Unique Values Across Worksheets in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I rarely use spreadsheets, but I thought creating a workbook for a contest would be really helpful. I am not sure if what I am asking is possible without a custom function. I am grateful for any and all help that may be offered.

I am trying to make a template that keeps track of a weekly writing contest. Each week is scored independently and then added up at the end of the month. I wanted to have a sheet that keeps track of the grand total. I thought I could do a UNIQUE() search of each worksheet and have it output a single column. As per [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124087/how-can-i-create-a-unique-list-of-data-across-multiple-rows-and-columns/124089) I've tried

```
=UNIQUE({'Week1'!B2:B,'Week2'!B2:B,'Week3'!B2:B,'Week4'!B2:B})
```

This pulls unique values for each sheet, but lines them up in multiple columns. I was hoping to just get all of the usernames in column A, and then use a lookup formula to add up the totals from each week in column B. [Here is the Proof of Concept workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IaJAgqYyRx4JkYMzRzLJrpQG_qE26gPLC2V-rTcGqXc/edit?usp=sharing) if anyone can take a look.

Again I appreciate any and all suggestions or directions to get this to work. If it can't be done I can just go to manually tabulating totals, but I was hoping to streamline my workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=UNIQUE(
   TRANSPOSE(
     SPLIT(
       CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(Week1!B2:B)&CHAR(9)))&
       CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(Week2!B2:B)&CHAR(9)))&
       CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(Week3!B2:B)&CHAR(9)))&
       CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(Week4!B2:B)&CHAR(9))),
     CHAR(9))
   )
  )`

Props-[Will Cervarich](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0iUsss82BYcs/?hl=ru)

---

[image: Screenshot]

---

Blindingly straightforward when it is broken down like this:

1. the unique names for each week are obtained,
2. a 'Tab' character is added,
3. the whole is wrapped in an arrayformula (to automatically list all values)
4. the lot is concatenated - resulting in a string of the unique names each followed by a tab.

   - the result looks like this:
     `User 1    User 2  User 3  User 4  User 5  User 6`
5. Rinse and repeat for each of the four weeks and joining all the weeks
6. Split this using char(9) as a delimiter. The result is a horizontal series of the individual unique names from the four weeks.
7. Transpose the names list to the vertical
8. Lastly, get the unique names of the vertical list

Comment: Thank you so much for both an answer and an explanation. I tried using TRANSPOSE(), but I didn't use it correctly I guess. This works really well, and I really can't thank enough for explaining how it all works at the end!

Answer (score 1):

`=UNIQUE({'Week1'!B2:B;'Week2'!B2:B;'Week3'!B2:B;'Week4'!B2:B})` also works