# How can I arrange the same data's in columns on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

This image shows the languages each individual wants to learn.

[image]

I want to sort the same data's into columns.
For example:
Spanish in the same column, English in the same column, Chinese in the same column.

How can I sort the columns and not sort the rows? (Formula)
Link to edit :D
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SfgLNy8_bJdkOMIINbrB3hNkj02DZORTByMm7kyW0I4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. Your image fails to show enough info of your data or the expected results. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask] and also specify if you are looking for a formula based solution or a script based solution (please don't say that any of them will work because that will could make the question too broad)

Comment: Welcome. You said _I want to sort the same data's into columns._ Would you please edit your spreadsheet to include an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Form Response spreadsheet with answers to "What language or languages do you want to learn?". Respondents could choose up to four languages. In total, 15 unique languages were selected in 102 selections spread across the four columns.

You want to "sort the same data's into columns. For example: Spanish in the same column, English in the same column, Chinese in the same column." You don't explain how or why this data would be used, nor do you provide an example. However you do have a chart of "What language or languages do you want to learn?", and presently this includes only one of the four Language columns.

---

This answer provides an alternative method to populate the data for the "What language or languages do you want to learn?" graph.

1. Create a new sheet,
2. Insert the formula in cell A1
3. Edit the "data range" for the graph to reflect the output from the query

`=ARRAYFORMULA(
  UNIQUE(
   QUERY(
    TO_TEXT({
     'Form Responses 1'!AB2:AB;
     'Form Responses 1'!AC2:AC;
     'Form Responses 1'!AD2:AD;
     'Form Responses 1'!AE2:AE
    }
   ), 
   "select Col1, count(Col1) 
    where Col1 is not null 
    group by Col1 
    order by Col1 
    LABEL count(Col1) ''",0
   )
  ) 
)`

---

**Query Output**

[image: Query Output]

---

**Revised Languages Graph**

[image: Revised Languages Graph]

---

Props: @User0
[How can I create a unique list of data across multiple rows AND columns?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124089/196152)